# Moving MySQL directory on an Amazon EC2 machine

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to have MySQL point to a directory on an EBS volume I mounted on my EC2 machine.
I took th following steps:

1. Stopped MySQL (`/etc/init.d/mysqld stop`) - successful
2. Created a MySQL directory on my volume, mounted on /vol (`mkdir /vol/mysql`)
3. Copied the contents of /var/lib/mysql to /vol/mysql (`cp -R /var/lib/mysql /vol/mysql`)
4. Chanded the owner and group of that directory to match the original (`chown -R mysql:mysql /vol/mysql`) - after this step, the 2 directories are identical.
5. Edited the /etc/my.cnf file (commented 2 original lines):

   ```
   [mysqld]
   \#datadir=/var/lib/mysql
   \#socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
   datadir=/vol/mysql
   socket=/vol/mysql/mysql.sock
   ```
6. Started MySQL (`/etc/init.d/mysqld start`) - **FAILED**

The error file /var/log/mysqld.log contains the following lines:

```
100205 20:52:54  mysqld started  
100205 20:52:54  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 43665  
100205 20:52:54 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.  
Version: '5.0.45'  socket: '/vol/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

No other errors are available.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Where can I find the error/s encountered by MySql?
3. If I restore the original lines, MySQL starts, leading me to believe it may be a permissions issue - but permissions are the same for both directories?

Thanks!

Comment: `cp -Rp` copies and preserves permissions.

Comment: Good tip for next time - still doesn't solve my problem :)

Comment: Best I can suggest is to set -x when you run the mysqld script (sh -x /etc/init.d/mysqld start) - at least that will show you the exact command that's failing, which will hopefully give you a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took Garth's suggestion and ran the script with `sh -x`. I found out there are permission issues when accessing the `mysql.sock` file. So I left the old one in the conf file, ran it again and ta-da it works and runs from the new location!

Thanks Gareth for showing me the way. I gave you a +1 on the comment but you did not post an answer.

Hopefully, this question will help some other people trying to do the same.

Comment: Glad to be of help !  You really figured out the problem, so you should vote for your answer as the right one.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer though. Completely forgot about mysqld being a shell script :) And here's another point for the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Try mount the original paths using bind.

Mount then shows:

```
/vol/etc/mysql on /etc/mysql type none (rw,bind)
/vol/lib/mysql on /var/lib/mysql type none (rw,bind)
/vol/log/mysql on /var/log/mysql type none (rw,bind)
```

And config file still looks as before:

```
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
```